# Why is the state changing on all of my list items and not just one? React.js, State, HandleChange, Modal

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, state, react-props

When using my modal to update user information, when they click a time slot, the information updates but it updates all of the slots with the same information. I only want the selected time slot's state to change once the modal form is completed. why is it that the modal form is changing the state of all the time slots?

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import './App.css';



import Modal from 'react-modal';

Modal.setAppElement('#root')

function App() {

  //state for modal and user info
  const [modalIsOpen, setModalIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber ] = useState("")

  // handle submit form for the modal
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setName(name)
    console.log(name)
    setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
    console.log(phoneNumber)
    
}


  
  
  return (
   

<div className="App">
       

      <h2>Hello world</h2>
    
      <Modal isOpen={modalIsOpen} onRequestClose={() => setModalIsOpen(false)}>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input type="text" required="required" name="name" placeholder="enter full name" value={name} onChange={(e)=> setName(e.target.value)}  />
          <input type="number" name="phoneNumber" required="required" maxLength="10" value={phoneNumber} placeholder="enter phone number" onChange={(e)=> setPhoneNumber(e.target.value)} />
          <button type="submit">Confirm</button>
          {/* <button onClick={()=> setModalIsOpen(false)}>close</button> */}
        </form>

      </Modal>
      

      {/* slot 1 */}
      <div className="time-slot-list">
        <ul>
          {name ? <li  className="time-slot redBg" onClick={()=> setModalIsOpen(true)}>
            9:00am
           
            <p>{name}</p>  
          </li> :  <li className="time-slot" onClick={()=> setModalIsOpen(true)}>
            9:00am
           
            </li>
        }
        {/* slot 2 */}
           {name ? <li className="time-slot redBg" onClick={()=> setModalIsOpen(true)}>
            10:00am
            
            <p>{name}</p>  
          </li> :  <li className="time-slot" onClick={()=> setModalIsOpen(true)}>
            10:00am
            
            </li>
          }
         </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  );
}






export default App;
```

Comment: "why is it that the modal form is changing the state of all the time slots?" It's because all your time slots use the same single state value. You will want to have separate state for each slot if you want to edit them independently.

Comment: the modal is used to change the information being inputed I did not expect all of the slots to change on submission. Have any idea on how I could use the modal but change the individual slots when selected?

Comment: I suppose it depends on what your slots represent? Do you want an unique `name` for each slot?

Comment: Yes I would like a unique name for each slot.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest creating an array of `name`/`phoneNumber` values for slots and use the index to identify which you want to open a modal for.

```
const [modalIndex, setModalIndex] = useState(null);
const [slots, setSlots] = useState([
  {
    id: 0,
    name: "",
    phoneNumber: ""
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "",
    phoneNumber: ""
  }
]);
```

Since you attach a `value` and `onChange` prop to each input I'm assuming you want fully controlled inputs, so create a change handler callback and use the current selected index to match the slot being updated.

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  setSlots((slots) =>
    slots.map((slot, i) =>
      i === modalIndex
        ? {
            ...slot,
            [name]: value
          }
        : slot
    )
  );
};
```

Update the modal to use the slot state.

```
<Modal
  isOpen={modalIndex !== null}
  onRequestClose={() => setModalIndex(null)}
>
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <input
      type="text"
      required="required"
      name="name"
      placeholder="enter full name"
      value={slots[modalIndex]?.name}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
    <input
      type="number"
      name="phoneNumber"
      required="required"
      maxLength="10"
      value={slots[modalIndex]?.phoneNumber}
      placeholder="enter phone number"
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
    <button type="submit">Confirm</button>
  </form>
</Modal>
```

And to open the modal and update a specific slot, use the `setModalIndex` state updater function to set the specific slot index.

```
<ul>
  {["9:00am", "10:00am"].map((time, index) => (
    <li
      key={index}
      className={`time-slot ${slots[index].name ? "redBg" : ""}`}
      onClick={() => setModalIndex(index)}
    >
      {time}
      <p>{slots[index].name}</p>
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

[image: Edit why-is-the-state-changing-on-all-of-my-list-items-and-not-just-one-react-js-st]

Comment: This works, but it only works on the first slot.

Comment: @wadaygo2 Oops, did a small refactor to map the slots at the last minute and forgot to switch to use the mapping index for setting modal index, codesandbox updated.